# php and mysql database turkish character

Tags: php, mysql

Hello friends i know this question has in stackoverflow but i search all question answer but not solition for me. My problem is mysql and php turkish character problem.

I am using this this `<meta>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

But turkish character looking this : Ã¼Å�Ã¼dÃ¼

I try db connection like this:

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'test');
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
$database = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

but turkish character problem continued.

my phpmyadmin 3 tables sum collation: **utf8_general_ci**

message table collation: **latin1_swedish_ci**

```
<?php
$Wall = new Wall_Updates();
if(isSet($_POST['update']))
{
$update=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['update']);
$data=$Wall->Insert_Update($id,$update);

if($data)
{
$msg_id=$data['msg_id'];
$message=tolink(htmlentities($data['message']));
$time=$data['created'];
$id=$data['uid_fk'];
$name=$data['name'];
$face=$Wall->Gravatar($id);
//$commentsarray=$Wall->Comments($msg_id);
?>
```

In this way screenshot link [click](https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t1.0-9/10253916_821414054553568_2610066493638772323_n.jpg)
How can I solve the problem of Turkish character.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "comment_ajax.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("#commentload"+ID).append(html);
$("#ctextarea"+ID).val('');
$("#ctextarea"+ID).focus();
 }
 });
}
return false;
});
```

Comment: Is the data coming from the DB or the page? My point; make sure your encoding in your editor is set as well.

Comment: @GerbenJacobs the data coming from the db

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### HTML Entities:

Judging by your [screenshot](https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t1.0-9/10253916_821414054553568_2610066493638772323_n.jpg), the database contains HTML encoded entities which means that sometime before saving your data in the DB you are altering it by applying `htmlentities` over it.

Unfortunately if your PHP version is `< 5.4` the optional parameter `$encoding` does not default to `UTF-8` so it treats your string like ASCII.

### Multi-byte vs. single-byte:

Because of this multi-byte characters are broken into single-byte characters and HTML encoded before being saved.

When retrieving the data from the database you HTML source code will have HTML entities (ex.: `&Atilde;`) but your browser will render them the way you're seeing them.

Not using `htmlentities` should fix your problem and is recommended or you could try using `html_entity_decode` before outputting the data (not sure if it won't cause more trouble than it fixes).

### How to check for HTML entities:

View the HTML source code of the site and check if there are any entities in the text fetched from the DB (ex.: `&Atilde;`).

Comment: my phpmyadmin screenshot it this [click](https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/t31.0-8/893090_821424991219141_1972581502635943674_o.jpg) What can i do plese tell me. I try to make htmlentities but problem continued. and also this is my script page click this [mywebpage](http://www.ecowebtr.com/wall2/index.php)

Comment: I can't do your work for you. Check what my answer tells you to check. If it confirms my findings then do what my answer tells you to do.

Comment: If you do not understand what needs to be done reread the answer and ask questions about the things you do not understand. Don't make me guess everything for you -- I can't know what isn't working unless you give me information and I can't know what you don't understand unless you tell me.

Comment: dear i understand your answer and i try html_entity_decode but turkish character looks like this Ä�Ã¼Å�iÃ¶Ã§Ä± = ğüşiöçı . I did `utf-8` character encoding. but Turkish characters are not displayed. where I'm going to add this code `html_entity_decode`

Comment: Did you first try removing the `htmlentities` operation used before inserting into the DB (obviously this means deleting the current data from the DB and reinserting it)?

Comment: yes i try this it works now but if you check my project you see when i write ş,ğ,ü,ç,ö,ı it looks like  Å�,Ä�,Ã¼,Ã§,Ã¶,Ä± so when i Refresh the page character looks normal.click this  [link](http://www.ecowebtr.com/wall2/index.php) I think ajax utf-8 problem now. Can you tell ajax utf-8 settings ? I update my question to add my some ajax code

Comment: When does the AJAX occur? What do I need to click to see it working? Should I add a new comment?

Comment: Sir, thank you very much for your help. The problem was solved thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
  mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
  @mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die( "Unable to select database");
  mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

Working ok with greek for me

Answer (score 0):

It is better for you to change your table's encoding to `utf8` and connect to mysql like this:

```
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
$database = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query('set names "utf8" collate "utf8_turkish_ci" ');
```

Comment: I think saying 'not working' could not bring about any conclusion. what was the error message did you get?

Comment: I do not get any errors. Turkish characters involved in the following way AIAA ¶ Ã §

Comment: did you set your database's encoding as utf8? try to set like this, if you have phpmyadmin it will be very easy.

Comment: Utf8_general_ci in phpMyAdmin all table fields have been set.  can you check this [link](http://goo.gl/4vccUW)

Comment: it looks like this i will create an image for you click this link [screenshot](https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t1.0-9/10253916_821414054553568_2610066493638772323_n.jpg)

Comment: Judging by your screenshot, the database contains HTML encoded entities. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Put this line below $database variable line and Try

`mysql_set_charset('utf8',$database);`

and while inserting this kind of data, you have to use `N` along with your value in your query  `N('$yourvalue')`

Comment: might possible, restart apache and then try, its just the try hannn!  :)

Comment: can you check this link [screenshot](https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t1.0-9/10253916_821414054553568_2610066493638772323_n.jpg)

Comment: I thought `N` was only for SQL servers

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and solved it like that

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "tamirat";

$co = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
mysqli_set_charset($co, 'utf8');
```

Just write the connection stuff first and write 'utf8'. I hope this will help.